# Symfony 2 app_dev.php vs app.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, path

How can I use JS/JQuery distinguish whether or not a page is requested via app_dev.php or app.php?

I would like to know so that I can change the route requested in a jquery ajax call. So my JQuery Ajax call will either know whether to use app_dev.php or app.php (by looking at which was used to request the current page). So it will choose whether

```
path = www.example.com/app.php/stuff_to_request
```

or

```
path = www.example.com/app_dev.php/stuff_to_request
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you want to get the absolute url of one of your route when using some JavaScript code.

If the JavaScript/JQuery code you have is inside a twig template, you can use the [`url`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages) function:

```
path = {{ url('route', {'param': value}) }}
```

If it's part of a .js file, you could use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle):

```
path = Routing.generate('route', {'param': value}, true)
```

If using the latest solution, **don't forget** to add the option `"expose"=true` to your route.